# How to check if an object is in an element list of a numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy

For example, I have a list `l`.

```
l = np.array([[1,2], [3], [2,4]])
```

I hope to check which elements of the array contain 2.

By using a list comprehension, I can achieve it easily but not efficiently.

```
result = [2 in element for element in l]
```

Can I use `numpy` to get result more efficiently.

Thanks.

Comment: Could there be more than one occurance of the search number `2` in any of the lists?

Comment: Short answer: No. Look at the type of `l`: `array([[1, 2], [3], [2, 4]], dtype=object)`. Numpy has no way of operating on object arrays the same way it would floats and ints.

Comment: Also, that is a list comprehension, not a generator.

Comment: @Coldspeed Thank you.

Comment: What makes you think your list comprehension is inefficient? Is that really a bottleneck in your code?

Comment: @Chris_Rands The code is OK but I have a large dataset which has more than three million elements and I need to check whether 1999 different objects are in each element in the array.

Comment: That sounds like a job for `set` operations possibly

Comment: @liuyihe But the sample in the question is only looking for one number `2`. Could you post a more representative sample case?

Comment: @liuyihe When you said - `"need to check whether 1999 different objects are in each element in the array."`. Did you mean `whether ALL of those 1999 different objects are in each element in the array` or  `whether ANY of those 1999 different objects are in each element in the array`? Again, a representative sample case would be the best way to interpret your comments to the question.

Comment: @Divakar Sorry, I didn't express clearly. In fact you have solved my problem and do not need to worry about my comment above. What I need to do next is just: `for item in items: in_eachlist(l, item)` and `assert len(items) == 1999`. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one approach -

```
def in_eachlist(l, search_num):
    mask = np.concatenate(l) == search_num
    lens = [len(i) for i in l]
    return np.logical_or.reduceat(mask,np.concatenate(([0], np.cumsum(lens[:-1]))) )
```

Basically, we are getting a `1D` array from the input array of lists and comparing against the search number, giving us a mask. Then, we check if there's any `True` value within each interval with [`np.logical_or.reduceat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.reduceat.html) (Thanks to `@Daniel F` on improvement here as I had used `np.add.reduceat` earlier and then looked for any `sum > 1`), giving us the desired output.

Sample run -

```
In [41]: l
Out[41]: array([[1, 2], [3], [2, 4]], dtype=object)

In [42]: in_eachlist(l,2)
Out[42]: array([ True, False,  True], dtype=bool)

In [43]: in_eachlist(l,3)
Out[43]: array([False,  True, False], dtype=bool)

In [44]: in_eachlist(l,4)
Out[44]: array([False, False,  True], dtype=bool)
```

Comment: Why `add.reduceat()>0` when you could do `logical_or.reduceat()`?

Comment: @DanielF Thanks, major improvement there! Edited.

Comment: Thanks! The operation time is reduced from 2.4s to 400ms.

Comment: @liuyihe, depending on the output you want after checking the 1999 values you mentioned, it is possible to make this even faster (thinking `np.in1d`, although @Divakar might have even fancier tricks in mind.)